Is it possible with nodejs + vue to host a webapp in dynamic virtual path?
I have a nodejs/expressjs application with a vue2 application.
In my node ENV VARS, I'm capable of setting BASE_URL and host the nodejs application under that virtual path.
BASE_URL: /myapp/
Will result the node js application to run under /myapp/api/v1/...
The problem is the vue2 application.  That one gets build.
There is a publicPath, and the works, but it's not dynamic.  It's fixed and set during build.
Setting the publicPath to '' works partially.  It will make the files relative to the main path and the index.html will be found.  So far so good.  But then all the assets can't be loaded, like images and fonts.
So is this indeed possible or not ?
I tried

_webpack_public_path_
prefixing the urls with ~ or @ or ~@
set publicPath to './'

I just don't manage to make the assets relative to the virtual path.
I just hope it's possible by setting BASE_URL in nodejs and make this dynamic AFTER build.
